# Troubles trying to add attributes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add dynamically a row in jquery, this is my code:

```
var row = $('<tr />')
    .append($('<td />'))
    .append($('<td>' + response.nome + '</td>'))
    .append($('<td />', {
        style: "text-align:center"
    }).append($('<input />', {
        type: 'image',
        src: 'nienteico.png',
        'class': 'ajaxEdit',
        id: '1.' + response.row_id
    }).css({
        cursor: 'pointer',
        width: '40px',
        height: '40px',
    }).click(function() {
        cambiastato('1.' + response.row_id);
    })));
```

In particular, as regards the last  element i'm expecting to get 'id' attribute and one 'onclick function'. Something like:

```
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>uytredsgfh</td>
<td style="text-align:center">
<input type="image" src="nienteico.png" style="cursor:pointer; width:40px; height:40px" id="1.15" class="ajaxEdit" onclick="cambiastato(1.15)"> 
</td>
</tr>
```

The first two  elements are correctly written, but unfortunally this is what i get for the last one (id attribute and onclick function missed!)

```
<td style="text-align:center">
<input type="image" src="nienteico.png" class="ajaxEdit" style="cursor: pointer; width: 40px; height: 40px;">
</td>
```

Any help or suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you would expect.

Your `id` is invalid because it starts with a number - see [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name). jQuery is probably rejecting it because of this.

The click event is not written as an attribute of the tag. Instead it is hooked up as a property of the DOM element the tag represents. You will probably find that it works if you put the `input` on the page and click it.

If you do want to explicitly output the `onclick` and other attributes into the tag, you can just set them in the initial tag creation call:

```
var row = $('<tr />')
    .append($('<td />'))
    .append($('<td>' + response.nome + '</td>'))
    .append($('<td style="text-align:center" />')
       .append($('<input onclick="cambiastato(1.' + response.row_id + ');" type="image" src="nienteico.png" class="ajaxEdit" id="1.' + response.row_id + '" />')
         .css({
            cursor: 'pointer',
            width: '40px',
            height: '40px',
         })
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. jQuery is not adding attributes to the element it is adding an [Event Listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to the  DOM. In other words it will not show up in the markup even when it is working. Try adding a `console.log` statement to the listener and trying it out - it should work.

On a side note there are a few best practices that might help keep your code cleaner and more maintainable.

1. When working with jQuery elements in JavaScript people usually use a `$` to prefix variable names. In your example this would be `$row`.
2. Since you are composing nested elements it is often much cleaner to create a variable to each of the major ones and bring them together at the end. This reduces the surface area effected when you have to do refactors. In your example I might pull the `$input` element into it's own variable.
3. Inline styles and particularly styles written in JavaScript are considered bad practice. If possible you should try and add a class then style the class in your stylesheet.

Best of luck!